# How to remove unused languages with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, localization

I want to know how to remove unused languages from application with Android Studio, like French or German (unused Languages for me). I only need English and Arabic.

Comment: Is it an application that you created?

Comment: by removing folders `res/values-xx` where `xx` is language qualifiers which you don't use it

Comment: Alex .. bro i am just editing it is my first time ever

Comment: selvin i will try to do it but what happens when i choose any language from them at starting messages

Answer (score 3):

From Developer Documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor)

To delete a language, do the following:

You can delete a language in the Translations Editor by deleting every value in the column (see Edit, add, or delete text), or you can delete the project folder for that language, as follows:

In the Project > Android panel on the left, select ModuleName > res.
Right click the values-* folder for the language you want to delete. For example, values-hi for Hindi or strings.xml (in).
From the drop-down list, select Delete to delete the folder and its strings.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do this now:

1. Open Translations Editor (double <kbd>Shift</kbd> and **Open Translations Editor**)
2. Right click the desired column and select **Remove Locale**